# My stringstream is not reading input

Tags: c++, string, templates, stringstream

Class A contains a template function which reads an object into a string by first passing it to a stringstream and then converting the stream to a string.

For the life of me, I don't know why these objects aren't passed to the stream. What could be the problem? What could I try to resolve this?

```
class A
{
public:

    template<class T>
    void Input(const T&);

private:
    std::string result;
};

template<class T>
void A::Input(const T& obj)
{
    //Pass object to the stream
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << obj;

    //After this line, result == "" with size 1 (??), no matter the input
    result = ss.str();

    int test = 1234;
    ss << test;

    //Even with a test int, result == "" with size 1 (???)
    result = ss.str();
}
```

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2012.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7653210eb01d23b6b89cca75f10f4c9b-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)

Comment: How can I tell if ss << obj is working?

Comment: @Frank `bool ok = (ss << obj);` will be `false` if there was an error.  The stream may be in an error state.  You can also test `(bool)ss` or `ss.good()` after the operation.  Possibly a null character was written to the string, which may explain why it appears empty with a size of 1.

Comment: What type is `T` when you are testing this?

Comment: @Frank, The same code I linked to works for me on VS2012. Please provide a complete example that has the issue.

Comment: Solved. Thanks guys. It turns out I was passing a null character (0) to the function.